# unable to build valgrind for armv7 in yocto

Tags: valgrind, yocto, armv7

Unable to build valgrind in yocto
I have highleted the problem i am facing

```
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized argument in option '-march=armv7ve'
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc: note: valid arguments to '-march=' are: armv2 armv2a armv3 armv3m armv4 armv4t armv5 armv5e armv5t armv5te armv6 armv6-m armv6j armv6k armv6s-m armv6t2 armv6z armv6zk armv7 armv7-a armv7-m armv7-r armv7e-m armv8-a armv8-a+crc iwmmxt iwmmxt2 native
make[5]: *** [intdiv-intdiv.o] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/sarjoodeen/Project/2018/Nippon/YOCTO/iwG22M-release-bsp/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/valgrind/3.15.0-r0/build/none/tests/arm'
make[4]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/sarjoodeen/Project/2018/Nippon/YOCTO/iwG22M-release-bsp/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/valgrind/3.15.0-r0/build/none/tests/arm'
make[3]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sarjoodeen/Project/2018/Nippon/YOCTO/iwG22M-release-bsp/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/valgrind/3.15.0-r0/build/none/tests'
make[2]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sarjoodeen/Project/2018/Nippon/YOCTO/iwG22M-release-bsp/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/valgrind/3.15.0-r0/build/none'
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sarjoodeen/Project/2018/Nippon/YOCTO/iwG22M-release-bsp/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/valgrind/3.15.0-r0/build'
make: *** [check] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/home/sarjoodeen/Project/2018/Nippon/YOCTO/iwG22M-release-bsp/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/valgrind/3.15.0-r0/build'
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Function failed: do_compile_ptest_base (log file is located at /home/sarjoodeen/Project/2018/Nippon/YOCTO/iwG22M-release-bsp/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/valgrind/3.15.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile_ptest_base.29480)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the cross gcc doesn't contain the support for armv7ve architecture. The support for armv7ve has been added in gcc-4.9 as evident from the gcc Changelog https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html. Please check your gcc recipe in yocto sources and make sure the gcc version is 4.9 or greater.